# Android Dark Theme with Light ActionBar (Sherlock Compatible)

Tags: android, styles, themes, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

Maybe its just me being stupid, but I have struggled to implement a custom Theme, which is Dark and a Light ActionBar. We have access to Light with Dark ActionBar, but not the opposite.

I dont know if this is against the style guidelines or something, but I am looking for a decent solution for this. Now this is for everything, not just a couple of bits, but everything associated with the ActionBar (ActionButtons, Overflow Menu's Split ActionBar, etc).

If possible I need this to be ActionBarSherlock compatible as well.

I have started using the following, but I am sure its far from complete and I will start scratching my head again soon when I start adding more features

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">?attr/textColorPrimaryInverse</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse</item>
    <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_custom</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_solid_custom</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_solid_custom</item>
</style>
```

Any help would be appreciated on this :)

Thanks,

Adam

Comment: hav u tried **Theme.Sherlock.Light**

Comment: Thanks but thats not what I am asking...